# Check values present or not from comma separated values

Tags: jquery, mysql, procedure

I am having the string comma separated. i would like to check the individual comma separated value present or not in database. I don't knew, how to separate the string and how to pass the separated  string to while loop. Please help me to do this.

My login

```
String val = '1234,2345,45566,3243,656656';
string[] arra = val.split(',');
for(int i=0; i<=arra.lenght;i++)
{
  //select * from tbl where fld_no =arra[i];
}
```

I don't know is this possible or not. If it's possible means, tell me the way to create this.

Comment: You can't use mysql with jquery you need a server side language to access mysql please elaborate what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

### you could use the below jquery code snippet

```
var str = '1234,2345,45566,3243,656656';
var arr= str.split(",");
$.each( arr, function() {
  //call handler here which would go and check the DB 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear! But if what you want to do is to return the rows from your database which contains values in any of the following '1234,2345,45566,3243,656656', then you don't need array.

In your MySQL query execute this query

```
SELECT * FROM YourTableName WHERE TheColumeName IN ('1234,2345,45566,3243,656656');
```

The above query will return all the rows that has TheColumeName either 1234 or 2345 or 45566 or 3243 or 656656.

It is better you make a SINGLE database call and iterate through the returned values than running a LOOP of database calls. That's a very bad practice.